# How do you get an HTML string from JSX without React. I'm using SolidJS for example

Tags: javascript, html, solid-js

I'm not using React, so this won't work

```
ReactDomServer.renderToString(<div>p</div>)
```

I'm currently rendering the jsx in a hidden div with an id on the browser and then using

```
document.getElementById(id).outerHTML
```

to get the HTML, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SolidJS components actually render as plain DOM nodes, so you can actually just use all of the DOM nodes properties

In your specific example that could be something like

```
const SomeComponent = <div></div>;
console.log(SomeComponent.outerHTML) //this will output -> "<div></div>"
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently rendering the jsx in a hidden div with an id on the browser and then using

```
document.getElementById(id).outerHTML
```

to get the HTML, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution

Comment: Why have you posted information supplemental to your question as an answer?

Comment: It is a possible solution.  It's also supplemental to the question.  It's both.

Answer (score 0):

JSX is not directly supported by the browser so it requires a compiler to be compiled into proper HTML that means you have to use a library like Solid, React ect.

In Solid, you don't need to render it into a hidden div, just don't output it to the DOM.

```js
import { render, renderToString } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal } from "solid-js";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = createSignal(0);
  const increment = () => setCount(count() + 1);

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={increment}>
      {count()}
    </button>
  );
}


function App() {
  
  let el = <Counter />

  const increment = () => {
    console.log((el.outerHTML));
  };

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={increment}>
      get content
    </button>
  );
}

render(() => <App />, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

There is `renderToString` in Solid to support server side rendering, but it appears it does not work in browsers.